# How to reshape (10,) to (1,10)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Let x be a matrix of shape (10,)

I have tried

```
x=np.reshape(x, [1,10])
```

it occurs error

error: cannot reshape x to [1,10] which size is (10,)

How to deal with it?

Comment: The transposed array `x.T`?

Comment: Don't pass `x` into `reshape()`, call `.reshape()` on `x`: `x = x.reshape([1,10])`

Comment: @Grismar oh, that works. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is of shape (10,), `np.array([x])` would be of shape (1,10).

That would create a copy of the array, so it maybe is not the most efficient solution, but is simple.

Answer (score 2):

`-1` in `reshape` function represents the first shape:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print(a.shape) # (10,)
a = a.reshape(1, -1)
print(a.shape) # (1, 10)
```